# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaListenerContainerFactory'

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

Подключил Kafka в Spring Boot, взяв нужные классы из другого проекта, в котором реализован простой Spring, на Tomcat. Зависимость в сборке:

```
compile 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.1.0.RELEASE'
```

Класс слушателя:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Autowired
    ResourcesProperties properties;

    @Autowired
    JsonDeserializer jsonDeserializer;

    @Bean
    public JsonDeserializer jsonDeserializer() {
        return new JsonDeserializer() {
            @Override
            public Object deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<?> batchFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Long, AbstractDto> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        factory.setMessageConverter(new BatchMessagingMessageConverter(converter()));
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<?> singleFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Long, AbstractDto> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setBatchListener(false);
        factory.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<Long, AbstractDto> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, properties.getKafkaServer());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, properties.getKafkaGroupId());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public StringJsonMessageConverter converter() {
        return new StringJsonMessageConverter();
    }
}
```

Валится со следующим исключением:

> 2018-02-02 15:08:15.356  WARN 12159 --- [           main]
>   ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'kafkaListenerContainerFactory' defined
>   in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'kafkaListenerContainerFactory' parameter 1; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies
>   as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решился путём простого переименования `batchFactory()` в `kafkaListenerContainerFactory()`. Как выяснилось, нужен хотя бы один слушатель с таким именем, при неограниченном количестве слушателей с другими именами.